# Bootstrap Theme focus text field issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I am facing a small problem while using Bootstrap Theme. I have a popup which have id "swipe-popup" and this popup have an text field which have id "swip-card-number". All i want is to focus this text field when some one open this popup. Write now i am using following code and it is working perfectly fine on my laptop.

**JS:**

```
$("#swipe-popup").modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#swip-card-number").focus();
});
```

When i test it on my mobile device it dont work. Can you please explain why this is happening.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Well this thing can't be done in mobile devices. In mobile devices when we tab on textbox a system call is generated and it opens the virtual keyboard. So due to security reasons browser can't generate a system call. This is the main reason due to which there is no website which when loads automatically opens the keyboard.